# Распаковать ZIP-архив, не имея достаточного свободного места на диске

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip

Имеется сервер на Ubuntu. На нём свободно 30 GB. В одной из его директорий находится ZIP-архив размером 70 GB. В архиве 4 млн. изображений, находящихся в разных папках. Степень сжатия небольшая и в распакованном виде данные поместятся на сервер.

**Как можно распаковать архив?**

Мне удалось найти [скрипт](https://superuser.com/a/1371106), который использует [`fallocate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) для уменьшения количества занимаемых файлом блоков в процессе распаковки. Но часть системных вызовов заканчивается неудачей, а распаковка файлов этим способом по подсчётам займёт 4 дня. Пока что не рассматриваю этот вариант.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128034/discussion-on-question-by-nomnoms12--zip----).

Comment: Если степень сжатия **небольшая**, данные никак не поместятся на сервер. Легче почистить место или подключить дополнительный диск.

Comment: @0andriy если степень сжатия небольшая, это как раз означает, что данные отлично поместятся, потому что они могут занять место, занимаемое zip-архивом

Comment: @nomnomы12 можно воспользоваться ОЗУ. На серверах обычно устанавливают большое количество оперативной памяти. Создать в оперативной памяти папку и туда распаковать. 

https://github.com/akimdi/wiki/blob/master/docs/archlinux.md#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-tmpfs-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Tmpfs

Comment: Например, если на серверe стоит 128 гб оперативной памяти, то архив спокойно может туда распаковаться.

Comment: @Ivan Как вариант. Но выделенный сервер — дорогое удовольствие. У меня VPS, всего 2 GB ОЗУ

Comment: а выкачать его к себе, распаковать - тоже не предоставляется возможным? или же в настройках VPS арендовать на пару суток увеличение ОЗУ, туда в оперативку распаковать, провести все манипуляции которые вы хотите. Так тоже нельзя? насколько я знаю на большинстве популярных VPS дают такую возможность. А потом обратно уменьшить ОЗУ и всё. Тоже нет?? не получится у Вас так??

Answer (score 3):

**UPD** Да, вариант отпал. `zip -d` создаёт копию исходного архива, поэтому требуется удвоенное пространство на диске, чтобы этот рецепт сработал.

Почему бы вам не попробовать извлекать файлы в режиме "извлёк-удалил"?

```
#!/bin/bash
ARCHIVE=test.zip
echo -n "DEBUG: space used: "; du -s . # DEBUG

last="$(zipinfo -1 $ARCHIVE | tail -1)"
while [ "$last" != "Empty zipfile." ]; do
        unzip -o "$ARCHIVE" "$last"
        zip -d "$ARCHIVE" "$last"
        echo -n "DEBUG: space used: "; du -s . # DEBUG
        last="$(zipinfo -1 $ARCHIVE | tail -1)"
done
```

Скрипт берёт последний файл из списка файлов в архиве, извлекает этот файл и удаляет извлечённый файл из архива. Так как удаляется файл из хвоста архива, то архив точно сжимается на диске.

Для проверки я сгенерировал семь случайных бинарных файла по 4 мб размером, упаковал их в архив и распаковал этим скриптом.

```
DEBUG: space used: 57352        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/7.bin
deleting: samples/7.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57352        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/6.bin
deleting: samples/6.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57352        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/5.bin
deleting: samples/5.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57348        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/4.bin
deleting: samples/4.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57348        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/3.bin
deleting: samples/3.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57348        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/2.bin
deleting: samples/2.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57348        .
Archive:  test.zip
  inflating: samples/1.bin
deleting: samples/1.bin
DEBUG: space used: 57344        .
Archive:  test.zip
deleting: samples/
        zip warning: zip file empty
DEBUG: space used: 57344
```

Видно, что по мере распаковки размер папки не увеличивается.

Comment: `zip -d` просто создаёт новый архив и после создания удаляет старый, то есть такой способ потребует 140 ГБ свободного места (на временное хранение одновременно двух архивов, старого и нового) и дохренища времени на создание нового архива (копировать 70 ГБ это всё-таки небыстро)

Comment: @andreymal да, действительно, `inode` меняется.

Comment: `zip -d` создаёт временный файл... при реальной нехватке места нерабочий способ...